# How to programmatically get the sharedUserId

Tags: android

I want to programmatically get the sharedUserId of an app that I already have published in the Play Store, so that I can set the sharedUserId of my new app to the existing app's sharedUserId.

I know what you're thinking. Just have both apps use the same hardcoded sharedUserId. Well, it appears that changing the manifest for the old app and then installing it results in an Application Installation Failed error:

[image: Application Installation Failed error]

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is: stop using `sharedUserId`. That is mostly for device manufacturers, with pre-installed app suites, greater ability to leverage storage shortcuts, and a tendency towards writing unreliable crap. Ordinary apps should be using IPC mechanisms to interact with other peer apps, so that you're not trying to change files behind an app's back, which may cause all sorts of problems (e.g., invalid cached data, file locking contention).

The next-best answer is: get the value of the old app's `sharedUserId` from the app's source code, to use that value in the new app.

The literal answer is: get the `PackageInfo` of the other app via [`getPackageInfo()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)). There is a `sharedUserId` field on `PackageInfo` that has what you want.